# How to derive boolean value via SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't `update` or `insert`; i can only `select`. What i have so far is

```
    SELECT
    m.id AS "Customer #", m.email AS "Email", p.purchased AS "Made Purchase"
    FROM customer.profile AS m
    LEFT JOIN customer.purchased AS p ON p.id = m.id
    WHERE p.status = "SUCCESS"
    GROUP BY m.id
```

`customer.profile` tables structure is:

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a@gmail.com |
| 2 | row |
| 3 | row |
| 4 | row |
| 5 | row |

`customer.purchased` tables structure is:

| purchase_id | customer_id | purchase_price | purchase_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | $20.00 | "SUCCESS" |
| 2 | 2 | $20.00 | "PENDING" |
| 3 | 3 | $20.00 | "SUCCESS" |

Desired output of `SELECT` is:

```
| Customer #     | Email           | Made Purchase     |
|----------------|-----------------|-------------------|
| 1              | a@gmail.com     | 1                 |
| 2              | b@gmail.com     | 0                 |
| 3              | c@gmail.com     | 0                 |
| 4              | d@gmail.com     | 1                 |
| 5              | e@gmail.com     | 0                 |
```

`customer.purchased` will always have a subset of `customer_id` from `customer.profile`. How do i go about this using my original query?

Comment: How is the output related to the tables? It doesn't seem there is any purchases made by customer with id 4, but your example seem to have a true value for that customer. Also customer with it 3 seems to have a false in your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT m.id as customer_number, m.email AS email,
       (p.id IS NOT NULL) AS made_purchase
FROM customer.profile m LEFT JOIN
     customer.purchased p
     ON p.id = m.id AND p.status = 'SUCCESS'
GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what i was looking for. I was trying to avoid using an EXISTS statement. Thank you! Is the made_purchase always going to 1 or 0 or does it act as a count?

Comment: @Jordan . . . It is always 0 or 1 (what passes for a boolean in MySQL).

Comment: thank you! It's funny you figured out exactly what i was trying to do while i was still trying to do the table markdown and struggling haha.